# React component does not show up after importing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just starting to learn React from this [tutorial](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/the-mern-stack-tutorial-building-a-react-crud-application-from-start-to-finish-part-1-d8d701c2995). I created components and imported them on my App.js.

However, I noticed that the components are not showing up when I run npm start (i.e. "Welcome to Create Todo Component!!" does not appear). I am also not receiving any error messages. Am I doing something wrongly?

Thanks in advance!

App.js

```
...

import CreateTodo from "./components/create-todo.component";
import EditTodo from "./components/edit-todo.component";
import TodosList from "./components/todos-list.component";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
...
            <Route path="/" exact component={TodosList} />
            <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditTodo} />
            <Route path="/create" component={CreateTodo} />
...
```

create-todo.component.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class CreateTodo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Welcome to Create Todo Component!!</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using '/create' as url?

Comment: Are your `<Route/>`s nested inside of a `<Switch/>`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually render your app to the DOM in order for it to display on screen, do you do that? Something like this:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I have this in index.js: 

`import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`

However, it still doesn't work.